# RegEx: Excluding a pattern from the match

Tags: regex, salesforce, regex-group

I know some basics of the RegEx but not a pro in it. And I am learning it. Currently, I am using the following very very simple regex to match any digit in the given sentence.

```
/d
```

Now, I want that, all the digits except some patterns like e074663 OR e123444 OR e7736 should be excluded from the match. So for the following input,

> Edit **398**e**997979** the Expression **9798729889** & T**900980980098**ext to see e081815 matches. Roll over matches or e081815 the expression e081815 for details.e081815 PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are e081815 supported. Validate your expression with Tests mode e081815.

Only bold digits should be matched and not any e081815. I tried the following without the success.

```
(^[e\d])(\d)
```

Also, going forward, some more patterns needs to be added for exclusion. For e.g. cg636553 OR cg(any digits). Any help in this regards will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: To clarify: `e997979` is matched because it's directly preceded by more digits, or...? Also: Which regex engine/language are you using?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Yes correct. So by now, I was using a simple /d for matching any digit in the string. But business has asked me to exclude any pattern with exxxxx( x being a digit preceded by letter e) from the match.

Comment: Just for the record. Where are you working in? Python?

Comment: No... Salesforce. Similar to Java. Just curious... Does this make any difference?

Comment: If you were working in python it could, but in general different apps use diferent regex flavors that do or do not allow certain syntax to be used. Therefor I was wondering =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<!\be)(?<!\d)\d+
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/6LlhUU/2).

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!\be) # make sure we're not right after a word boundary and "e"
(?<!\d)  # make sure we're not right after a digit
\d+      # match one or more digits
```

If you want to match individual digits, you can achieve that using the `\G` anchor that matches at the position after a successful match:

```
(?:(?<!\be)(?<=\D)|\G)\d
```

[Test it here](https://regex101.com/r/6LlhUU/4)

Comment: Nice! I think the OP also want to exclude `cg(any digits)` in the future. +1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Correct. Is there any way I can add more pattern for exclusion?

Comment: @ShaileshPatil, very crude you could do `(?<!\be)(?<!\bcg)(?<!\d)\d+`.

Comment: @Thefourthbird: One last question. I see the RegEx match returns the complete digits. Like for e.g. in This is my amount: 773663, it is returning me 773663 as a complete match. But what if I want to get the individual matches. Like, 7,7,3,6,6,3?

Comment: That is only possible with a few regex engines. Which one are you using?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: You can say it's JAVA.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use a capturing group with lookarounds

```
(?:\b(?!e|cg)|(?<=\d)\D)[A-Za-z]?(\d+)
```

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\b(?!e|cg)` Word boundary, assert what is directly to the right is not `e` or `cg`
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<=\d)\D` Match any char except a digit, asserting what is directly on the left is a digit
- `)` Close group
- `[A-Za-z]?` Match an optional char a-zA-Z
- `(\d+)` Capture 1 or more digits in **group 1**

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V2y0NQ/1)

Comment: Thank you! This helped too! I can use one of these or may combine these! Appreciate your quick help!

Comment: @ShaileshPatil If you want to have separate digits, you can use the `\G` anchor in JAVA `(?:\G|(?:\b(?!e|cg)|(?<=\d)\D))[A-Za-z]?(\d)` See https://regex101.com/r/rg75yq/1

Comment: Thanks! It worked! How can I incorporate into the answer given my Tim? Just curious.

Comment: I think you can use the same mechanism https://regex101.com/r/OMbays/1 But as you know that the match consists of a string with digits, you can also get the separate ones using code.

Comment: Ok. The reason I am asking is, I have to use the most efficient regex in terms of the execution time. Because it is being used in the Cloud hosted shared services application, the running time of a regex matters a lot.